# How to handle Negative Look Aheads/Behinds with Regex?

Tags: regex

Here is my scenario:

If the text contains dirty or rotten in any position, no matches should be found regardless of matching patterns.

If the text  without `dirty` or `rotten` contains either `red`, `greed`, or `yellow` followed by `apple`, `pear` or `peach`  it would be a match.

Here is what I have tried:

```
(?:.+(?:[^(dirty)|(rotten)].{1,30}))(?:green|red|yellow).(?:apple|peach|pear)(?:(?!(dirty|rotten))(?:$))
```

These should match:
I have an green apple
I have a yellow peach
I have  red and green apples

These should not:
I have a dirty red apple
I have a  green peach that is dirty
I have a yellow dirty apple

Comment: It is helpful to use formatting for code and other literal strings.

Comment: This part: [^(dirty)|(rotten)] does NOT do, what you think (it's a character group), it matches any character not mentioned (not the words).

Answer (score 0):

You might use the negative lookahead at the start checking the there is no occurrence of dirty or rotten.

Then match either red, green or yellow followed by apple peach or pear and place word boundaries `\b` around the words to prevent them being part of a larger word.

```
^(?!.*\b(?:dirty|rotten)\b).*?\b(?:red|green|yellow)\b.*\b(?:apple|peach|pear)\b.*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wHn86m/1)

---

If red, green or yellow can not occur before apple, peach or pear you could make use of a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) approach `(?:(?!(?:apple|peach|pear)).)*` matching any character except an newline without matching one of the options.

```
^(?!.*\b(?:dirty|rotten)\b)(?:(?!(?:apple|peach|pear)).)*(?:red|green|yellow)\b.*\b(?:apple|peach|pear)\b.*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/punGIh/1)